ckeditor5 re-applying create list & table row insert operations erroring
I'm trying to apply operations to the ckeditor5 editor.
There seem to be operations that increment the baseVersion and operations that don't.
I recorded the operations created while using the editor.
I gather the operations that have a baseVersion and apply them to the document, as below.
writer.batch.addOperation( op );
this.editor.model.applyOperation( op );
this.setCurrentVersion( operation.data.baseVersion + 1 );

most operations apply without issue - Insert, Split, Attribute.
However, when I try to apply operations involved in making an unordered list,
I apply:
 1. AttributeOperation, key: "listIndent" -- successfully applied
 2. AttributeOperation, key: "listItemId" -- successfully applied
 3. AttributeOperation, key: "listType" -- successfully applied
 4. Insert Operation:
     {
       'baseVersion': 7,
       'position': {
         'root': 'main',
         'path': [0],
         'stickiness': 'toNone'
        },
        'nodes': [
          {
            'attributes': {
              'listIndent': 0,
              'listItemId': 'e82c6ae82a34f6e11f25cbdeaf69f8200',
              'listType': 'bulleted'
             },
             'data': 'o'
          }
        ],
        'shouldReceiveAttributes': true,
        '__className': 'InsertOperation'
     } 
    -- ERRORS as below


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parent')
    at removeCustomMarkerElements (converters.js:322:24)
    at DowncastDispatcher.eval (converters.js:273:9)
    at DowncastDispatcher.fire (emittermixin.js:159:47)
    at DowncastDispatcher._testAndFire (downcastdispatcher.js:482:14)
    at DowncastDispatcher._testAndFireAddAttributes (downcastdispatcher.js:499:18)
    at Object.convertAttributes (downcastdispatcher.js:520:45)
    at DowncastDispatcher.eval (downcasthelpers.js:772:23)
    at DowncastDispatcher.fire (emittermixin.js:159:47)
    at DowncastDispatcher._testAndFire (downcastdispatcher.js:482:14)
    at DowncastDispatcher._convertInsert (downcastdispatcher.js:273:18)

The listItemId matches the newly created list.
Although the downcast dispatcher errors and the editor stops updating, further operations continue getting applied to the model as expected.
I notice that immediately preceeding the erroring "Insert" operation are three RootAttributeOperations that mirror AttributeOperations 1-3. I'm unsure of whether these also need applying when I'm replying operations. When I try to apply them in the order they were created using the editor, it still errors
Any idea why this is erroring, when other operations seem to work as expected?
UPDATE:
I've solved the list playback problem with the following code:
// FIX LIST OPS
if ( op?.nodes?.[ 0 ]?.attributes?.listItemId ) {
    return {
        ...op,
        nodes: [ {
            ...op.nodes[ 0 ],
            attributes: null
        } ]
    };
}
if ( op.key === 'listItemId' && op.newValue === null ) {
    return null;
}
if ( op.key === 'listIndent' && op.newValue === null ) {
    return null;
}
if ( op.key === 'listType' && op.newValue === null ) {
    return null;
}


I've now hit an issue applying an operation that adds a table row:

    'timestamp': 1713993409153,
    'baseVersion': 4,
    'data': {
        '__className': 'InsertOperation',
        'baseVersion': 4,
        'nodes': [
            {
                'name': 'tableRow'
            }
        ],
        'position': {
            'path': [
                0,
                1
            ],
            'root': 'main',
            'stickiness': 'toNone'
        },
        'shouldReceiveAttributes': false
    }
},

This fails, though if I add this to the tableRow node,
'children': [
    {
        'name': 'tableCell'
    }
],

the operation successfully creates the new row, though then subsequent operations erroneously add additional rows etc.
I'd value any guidance on working with re-applying operations, as it's not working as I expected, and it seems different things are happening when I'm re-applying operations than when they are applied in the course of regular document editing.
